# What is wrong with this solution if $\Omega$ is not convex?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I want to solve the equation $\partial_{xy} \psi = 0$ with $(x,y) \in \Omega$. In class we studied that a solution is $\psi(x,y) = \phi(x)+\varphi(y)$ when $\Omega$ is a convex set.
I don't see the problem if $\Omega$ is not convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\Omega = \left\{(x,y) ~|~ x \neq 0 \text{ and } y \neq 0 \right\}$, which is the plane with the axes removed, the function
$$
\psi(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
x & \text{if} & x>0, y>0 \\
x+y & \text{if} &x>0, y <0 \\
x-y & \text{if} & x<0, y>0 \\
y  & \text{if} & x<0, y<0
\end{array}\right.
$$
is solution of $\partial_{xy}\psi = 0$, but there is no functions $\varphi$ and $\phi$ such that $\psi(x,y)= \phi(x) + \varphi(y)$.

The problem is that while trying to solve $\partial_{xy}\psi=0$, you integrate, thus, you fix a constant of integration. This is possible only on an interval, and hence, this uses convexity.

Comment: How do we know there is no such $\phi$, $\varphi$?

Comment: By contradiction. If so, the first condition would imply something that is incompatible with the three other conditions.

Comment: Is it possible to construct an counter-example where $\Omega$ is open and connected?

Comment: To be honnest I don't know. I don't have a proof or a counterexample, but I think there will not exist any counterexample if $\Omega$ is simply connected. I have no idea for the non-simply connected case.